# Is there a definitive guide on various application pool identities and their permissions level?

Tags: configuration, installation, configuration-wizard

Is there a definitive guide on how to configure various application pool identities in SharePoint 2010?

Also, is there a way to reset all my app pools to the correct identity, in case they are all messed up? Will running PSConfig or the Configuration wizard help me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is a MSFT writeup on Application Pool and Service Accounts: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288210%28v=office.14%29.aspx There's too much in this article to post it here, and leaving anything out would be misleading.